# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream error while reading data from excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading data from excel file but getting above error
I have added all below dependencies to my pom:
poi 5.2.2 ,poiooxml 5.2.2, poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.2 ,commons-io 2.7
Still its not working. Please help

I have tries adding all dependencies

Comment: See [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204) -> `poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.2 ` does not fit to `poi-ooxml 5.2.2`. This needs `poi-ooxml-lite` of same version `5.2.2`. Also it needs `commons-io` in version  `2.11.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer without some more information.
Note that `NoClassDefFoundError != ClassNotFoundException`

With `NoClassDefFoundError` it could be that the class is on classpath, but there is an exception preventing it to load into the classloader.

It could also be the version of commons-io that you use, that can be too old and not include a newer type that is required on some other dependency.

Anyway, with a simple maven project, I can successfully instantiate an object of type `UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream` with following dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream e = new UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.out.println("All good");
}
```